# Decrypt function not working in Windows form C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, winforms, encryption

I am trying to decrypt from an encrypted word using c# in windows form. When I tried to use the function, I am getting an "ofield_encryptionkey" message in the message box.

Here is the Main. The encryption is working but when I tried to decrypt on the other end is not working.

```
 

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string TokenID = Decrypt("fU2vE9Pc9Wb2HQn3qTHWN66lnxWxgOkpLfbGmiOOlVq32r8q40Iqq8ql8mPCkgLx");
    MessageBox.Show(TokenID);
}

//Here's the function
public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "MAKV2SPBNI99212";
    cipherText = cipherText.Replace(" ", "+");
    var cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
    using (var encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        var pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x49, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6E, 0x20, 0x4D, 0x65, 0x64, 0x76, 0x65, 0x64, 0x65, 0x76 });

        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(cipherBytes, 0, cipherBytes.Length);
                cs.Close();
            }
            cipherText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(ms.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return cipherText;
}
```

Comment: this came a sample from aspsnippet.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos this encrypt-decrypt password as a sample in the site of aspsnippet[com]

Comment: You already said that. That doesn't mean anything

Comment: `ofield_encryptionkey` is simply the plaintext resulting from decryption.

Comment: @Topaco why not display the decrypted value?

Comment: Topaco is right. Decryption worked. That *is* the decrypted value. Had decryption failed, you'd get an error or get garbled text. The funny thing is, that searching for `MAKV2SPBNI99212` shows this code started as a *question* in 2014 and was copy-pastaed left and right. It resurfaces in questions since because people don't understand what the snippets do

Comment: The oldest result I found is [this completely inappropriate code from ASP Snippets](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Username-or-Password-stored-in-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) - it's completely inappropriate because passwords should never be stored in a reversible form. They're always salted and hashed, not encrypted. Never mind that SQL Server already had strong encryption in 2013.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the help. I  will look for another solution

Comment: Another solution to what? The decryption works. What did you expect to receive? If you want to *encrypt*, you'll have to use a different salt and password. `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is used to make brute-forcing the password harder, by encrypting using a hash of the password instead of the actual password.